# При впушивании строки в массив, выводит undefined

Tags: javascript

Пользуясь случаем хочу спросить мнение о решении задачки - "Ввести с клавиатуры текст предложения, завершить точкой. Сформировать
новую строку на основе исходной, в которой после каждого слова в скобках
указать номер слова в предложении (слова разделяются запятыми,
пробелами или тире). Например, если введено «Донецк – прекрасный
город», результирующая строка должна выглядеть так: «Донецк(1) –
прекрасный(2) город(3)».

Хочу выводить слова в массив а потом брать их из массива и соединять с каким то countom в строке, есть ли решение получше? Надо решать через обработку строки как массива!!!

А вот собственно сам код, почему вместо строк, слов. В массиве появляется undefined? как исправить такое поведение?

```js
let prom = "Донецк - прекрасный город";


function asd(prom) {
  var arr2 = [];

  for (i = 0; i < prom.length; i++) {
    let count = 0
    if (prom[i] == " ") {
      arr2.push(prom[count - i])
      count = i
    }

  }
  return arr2
}

console.log(asd(prom))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. на каждой итерации цикла обнуляется `count`, поэтому индекс всегда отрицательный, и, следовательно результат `prom[count - i]` - `undefined`
2. `prom[count - i]` - это получение одной буквы, а не подстроки. Для получения подстроки можно воспользоваться методом [`.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) либо [`.substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)
3. алгоритм может выглядеть следующим образом:

   1. пробег по символам строки
   2. если символ - разделитель и предыдущий символ был буквой - добавляем в результат номер слова
   3. добавляем в результат текущий символ

```js
let prom = "Донецк - прекрасный город";


function asd(prom) {
  var count = 1;
  var res = '';
  for (i = 0; i < prom.length; i++) {
    if ((prom[i] == " " || prom[i] == "-") && // проверяем разделители
      prom[i - 1].match(/\p{Alpha}/iu)) { // проверяем что предыдущий символ - буква
      res += '(' + count + ')';
      count += 1;
    }
    res += prom[i];
  }
  if (prom[prom.length - 1].match(/\p{Alpha}/iu)) { // если последний символ был буквой - учитываем последнее слово
    res += '(' + count + ')';
  }
  return res;
}

console.log(asd(prom))
```

Comment: Если в тексте появятся запятые работать не будет..

Comment: @Rudi, да, все нужные разделители проверяются в условии. Сейчас там только пробел и `-`

Comment: Интересное решение.

Answer (score 1):

undefined потому что `count - i` уходит в минус соответственно по отрицательному индексу в строке нет значения.

```js
let prom = "Донецк - прекрасный, город";
let n = 1;
function asd(prom) {
  let m = prom.split(" ")
  let res = m.map((e,i)=>{
    let nn = n;
    if(e.includes("-")) {
      return e
    }
    if(e.includes(",")){
      n++;
      return  `${e.slice(0,e.length-1)}(${nn})${e[e.length-1]}`;
    }    
    if(!e.includes("-")){
      n++;
      return  `${e}(${nn})`
    }
  })
  return res.join(" ")
}

console.log(asd(prom))
```

Comment: `n - 1;` - ничего не делает

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, не уследил. Поправил..